# Serializing Json Array, in NewtonSoft json can achieve single json multiple json gives error

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

```
var rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(www.text);
string code = rt.Code;
```

value is Serializing

But multiple json objects such as:

```
[
    {
        "Code": "0002",
        "Name": "Inspire #9898",
        "size": "10x10",
        "Company": "inspire",
        "Description1": "Textured Grey HighQuality",
        "Description2": "Fit For Kitchen,Bathroom and PlayArea Floor",
        "Price": "250",
        "Type": "1"
    }, 
    {
        "Code": "0004",
        "Name": "Inspire #98101",
        "size": "10x10",
        "Company": "inspire",
        "Description1": "Textured Grey HighQuality",
        "Description2": "Fit For Kitchen,Bathroom and PlayArea Floor",
        "Price": "250",
        "Type": "3,1"
    }
]
```

gives error as

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,.
>   Path '', line 1, position 203. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read ()
>   (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)

!!! I am not passing it to array !!!

```
[System.Serializable] 
public class RootObject 
{ 
    public string Code { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string size { get; set; } 
    public string Company { get; set; } 
    public string Description1 { get; set; } 
    public string Description2 { get; set; } 
    public string Price { get; set; } public string Type { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: can you share your ``RootObject``

Answer (score 0):

You need to de-serialize your `JSON` string into a `List`:

Model:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Description1 { get; set; }
    public string Description2 { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

var rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(www.text);
```

Comment: Sorry i am a Newbie but it hits error as: 'List<RootObject>' does not contain a definition for 'Code' and no accessible extension method 'Code' accepting a first argument of type 'List<RootObject>' could be found

Comment: import `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: Already using , problem is i want to serialize lists of object,,,

Comment: @akhilesh Can you show us your entire code for this process? The above answer will de-serialize your `JSON` string to your `Model` as `List`

Comment: '
[System.Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
        public  string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Description1 { get; set; }
        public string Description2 { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    
}'

Comment: 'public class BindTileDetails : MonoBehaviour
{
    int type = 0;
    public WWW www;
   
    void Start()
    {
       
        Details();
    }
    public void Details()
    {
        sucess();
        for (type = 1; type <= 5; type++)
        {
            string url = "http://*************.php?type=" + type;
            www = new WWW(url);
            StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www,type));
        }
       
    }'

Comment: 'IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www, int type)
    {
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log(type);
        Debug.Log(www.text);
        string datapass = www.text.Replace('[', ' ').Replace(']', ' ');
        var rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(datapass);
        string code = rt.Code;
        string name = rt.Name;
        string Size = rt.size;
        string company = rt.Company;
        string desc1 = rt.Description1;
        string desc2 = rt.Description2;
        string price = rt.Price;
        string tiletype = rt.Type;
    }'

Comment: @akhilesh Please update the code in the question and not in the comments